# Disabling buttons in matrix in OSX

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsbutton

How to disable few NSButtons in a matrix of push buttons? Each button has a specific tag and title. To achieve this functionality the button should be bordered or borderless?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `IBOutlet` for the `NSMatrix`.

Then :

```
[[self.buttonMatrix cellWithTag:1] setEnabled:NO];
```

Similarly for others. Instead of `tag`, you can also use `title`

EDIT, doing in loop

```
for (NSButtonCell *button in [self.matrix cells]) {
    if (button.tag==1) {
        [button setEnabled:NO];
    }
}
```

Comment: Not for the selected cell. While loading the window itself

Comment: can you Please display the old solution?

Comment: @user2118335: that  was valid only for checkbox or radio not for other buttons. what you want ?

Comment: NSString *button=[[self.matrixButtons  selectedCell] title];
if ([button isEqualToString:@"Some Title"]) {
    [[self.matrixButtons  selectedCell] setEnabled:NO];
}